# How to add value to a column in a record which is already saved in django

Tags: python, sql, database, django, aptana

I am trying to save a data in to a column but that record is already saved. I am working with django and sql

models.py

```
class P(models.Model):
   t=models.ForeignKey(T)
   q=models.TextField(max_length=500)
   c_a=models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I have other classes in the models.py

views.py

```
...
 P_object=P(t_id=T_object.id, q=q)
 P_object.save()
...
```

here i am saving only two columns and i want the third column to be saved separately later when i get an id from a other record

```
 A_object=A(q_id = q_object.id, a=a)
 A_object.save()
 P_object.c_a = A_object.id
```

But this code does not seem to work. Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"doesn't seem to work" is about as useless a problem's description can be. You've got the first two points ("here's what I do", "here's what I expect") right but you're missing the third one : "here's what I get". But anyway...

```
 A_object=A(q_id = q_object.id, a=a)
 A_object.save()
 P_object.c_a = A_object.id
```

Model instances are not automagically saved when modified, you have to save them by yourself. Just add

```
P_object.save()
```

and you should be fine. Else please post the whole traceback.

As a side note, any reason you don't use a`models.ForeignKey` field instead ?

Comment: i think he already said in below comments that he is doing `P_object.save()` again . Please refer to below answers and comments..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
class P(models.Model):
    t=models.ForeignKey(T)
    q=models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)    
    c_a=models.IntegerField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
```

if it doesn't solved the problem, then may be the P_object not defined(scope expired)

find the P_object using `objects.get` and save it again.

```
A_object=A(q_id = q_object.id, a=a)
A_object.save()
P_object=P.objects.get(t_id=T_object.id)
P_object.c_a = A_object.id
P_object.save()
```

Comment: your close to give right answer .. try to explain it with more information .. like from where did that `T_object` come from .